# How to set image UniformToFill stretch mode

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I'm coming from XAML world where we have image stretch mode of `Fill`, `UniformToFill`, and `Uniform`. I'm targeting to achieve `UniformToFill` mode in my iOS app. In iOS, I came across `ScaleToFill`, `AspectToFit`, `AspectToFill`, and many others. None of them fulfill my requirement.

Required behavior: `UIImageView` (image container) size in layout remains fixed. Scale image according to fixed size of `UIImageView` and maintain aspect ratio of image itself. Upon matching either of side (vertical, horizontal), clip rest of the image.

To illustrate it better, here's the screenshot; I'm looking to achieve third from left.

[Image stretch mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGCYv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML to iOS conversion is as follows.

`Fill`  =  `ScaleToFill`

`Uniform` = `AspectToFit`  &

`UniformToFill` = `AspectToFill`

This is the exact match. If you are not getting this result, then it means you have done mistake in something else. Otherwise, this is perfect matching.

Comment: For me, `UIImageView` spans beyond the layout constraints when `AspectToFill` is used. You're saying it's auto layout issue?

Comment: you should add following line : `imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true`, it is not auto layout issue, but it is due ios's behaviour, until you dont clip its bounds, it will go out of its bounds. You have another way to do this, you can also call this method `imageview.clipsToBounds = true`, this also works the same as above line, worked now?

Comment: Right. I'm going to try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, as I checked `clip subviews`, it worked. Is there any way I could adjust alignment? e.g. center align image to clip left and right sides?

Answer (score 0):

That's what `.ScaleAspectFill` does.

You are talking about a `UIImage` as a container ? I think you should look into `UIImageView`. Something like that would work ( that's written in `Swift` but easily adaptable to `Objective-C`

```
let image = UIImage(named: "your_image")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Thanks for correction. I actually meant `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` as content mode of your image view.

You can refer [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode) for more details.

It states about `scaleAspectFill`,

> The option to scale the content to fill the size of the view. Some
>   portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

`scaleAspectFit`

> The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

Try both to feel real difference.

Comment: Will do. But how come they aren't listed in dropdown in attribute inspector?

Comment: They are listed in attribute inspector as titled `mode` under `view`. `Aspect fill` is equivalent to `scaleAspectFill` and `Aspect fit` is equivalent to `scaleAspectFit`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The culprit was `clip subviews` property which was unchecked.